# How to show data in Flutter from Firestore collection based on the value in the array?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I need to remove documents - reviews/posts - from the stream, which the user has hidden. When a user decides to hide the post, the post collection's post-doc creates an array 'hidingUserId' of userIDs that has hidden it. refer to the pic, pls.[image: firestore data]

now I need to remove the post where the array 'hidingUserId' contains the currentUserId. I have tried the following, but it does not display errors in the log and it does not display the posts. Just circular progress circling on the screen.

```
Stream streams = postRef
      .orderBy('stars', descending: false)
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .snapshots();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
        children: [
     StreamBuilderWrapper(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          stream: streams.where((event) => event.data()['hidingUserId'] 
      == null
      || event.data()['hidingUserId'].contains(!currentUserId()) ?
          streams.forEach((event) => print(event))
          : Container(
      child: Center(
      child: Text('Nothing to show'),))),
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (_, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
            internetChecker();
            Review posts = Review.fromJson(snapshot.data());
                return posts.postId != null
            ? Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
              child: Posts(post: posts),
            )
                : Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Nothing to show'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
}
```

am new to Firestore, and I can't find the information I need. help appreciated very much! Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to remove the post from the database or do you want to just show posts except that post in the web page? If you want to remove it from the database then can you check if it is removed from there or not?

Comment: No, not to remove it from database. Just not show it to user who has hidden it.